# Como obter o mime de um arquivo através do Python?

Tags: python, mime-type

Como posso obter o Mimetype de um arquivo através do Python?

Não estou falando apenas de obter através da extensão, mas também lendo os metadados do arquivo.

Como posso fazer isso?

**Nota**: Tentei usar o `python-magic` no Windows, mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Solução com a [Python-magic](http://github.com/ahupp/python-magic):

```
import magic
m = magic.Magic(mime=True)
mime_type = m.from_file("arquivo.pdf")
print mime_type
```

**Edit:**

Segundo o site oficial da biblioteca `Python-magic` existem 2 fatores que podem fazer com que o código acima não funcione.

O primeiro fator consiste em um conflito de nomes de biblioteca pois existem duas bibliotecas chamadas `magic` para Python! A biblioteca correta seria a `Python-magic-0.4.13`.

O segundo fator (que pode causar o não funcionamento no Windows) são as dependências que precisam ser instaladas.

No Windows, o utilitário `file` precisa existir na máquina e seu path precisa ser passado como argumento no construtor:

```
import magic
m = magic.Magic(magic_file="C:\windows\system32\file.exe")
mime_type = m.from_file("arquivo.pdf")
print mime_type
```

O utilitário `file` compilado para Windows pode ser obtido [aqui](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm).

Mais detalhes podem ser obtidos [aqui](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Testado no Windows?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss O que exatamente não funcionou no Windows ?

Comment: Não sei. A pergunta possui a nota: "Tentei usar o python-magic no Windows, mas não funcionou.". Você postou a solução utilizando o python-magic, então acredito que tenha testado no Windows. Sim?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Existem 2 bibliotecas no python que usam o nome `magic`, trata-se de um conflito de nomes (ver o link da resposta). Se você esta usando a a biblioteca errada, provavelmente o código acima vai falhar. Talvez seu problema não tenha nenhuma relação com o Windows.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss O nome correto do pacote da biblioteca é `python-magic-0.4.13`.

Comment: Sim, só quis saber se havia testado no Windows, pois aparentemente o Wallace testou com essa biblioteca e não havia funcionado.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Editei a pergunta com uma explicação.

Answer (score 0):

### shlex:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

file_name = 'pdf.fake'
cmd = shlex.split('file --mime-type {0}'.format(file_name))
result = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
mime_type = result.split()[-1]
print (mime_type)
```

**Output:**

```
b'application/pdf'
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca `mimetypes`:

```
>>> import urllib, mimetypes
>>> 
>>> url = urllib.pathname2url('meu_arquivo.xml')
>>> print mimetypes.guess_type(url)
('application/xml', None)
```

Referência: https://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html

Comment: Lembrando que a função `urllib.pathname2url` foi realocada para o módulo `urllib.request` no Python 3, ficando [`urllib.request.pathname2url`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.pathname2url).

Comment: Se voce alterar a terminação do `meu_arquivo.xml` para `meu_arquivo.fake`, funciona?